# Convert FLAC files to MP3 in parallel on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, concurrency, linux, audio

I created a script to convert my FLAC music collection to MP3.  I did this so that I can play the MP3 files in my car, as the integrated head unit only supports MP3 and WMA files.  The script works on my Ubuntu system.  Are there any opportunities to improve its efficiency?

I chose to use `ffmpeg` to transcode and GNU parallel to utilize all CPU cores/threads.

## Iteration 1

```
 #!/bin/bash
 
 ## Converts flac to mp3
 
 if ! dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' ffmpeg | grep "ok installed"; then
 apt-get update  && apt-get install ffmpeg; fi
 
 if ! dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' parallel | grep "ok installed"; then
 apt-get update  && apt-get install parallel; fi
 
 parallel -i -j$(nproc) \
         ffmpeg -n -i {} -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 {.}.mp3 ::: */*/*/*.flac
```

## Iteration 2

```
 #!/bin/sh

 ## Converts flac to mp3

 die() { echo "$@" >&2; exit 1; }

 ### Check the preconditions

 if ! dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' ffmpeg | grep "ok installed"; then
     apt-get update  && apt-get install ffmpeg libmp3lame parallel;
 fi

 ####

 flac_to_mp3() {
     ffmpeg -n -i "$1" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k \
        -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "$2"
 }
 export -f flac_to_mp3

 parallel flac_to_mp3 {} '{.}.mp3' ::: */*/*/*.flac
```

Comment: `-i -j$(nproc)` is default and thus not needed.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## shellcheck

It is always a good plan to run your code through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/).  This only reveals a couple of issues:

1. Your `-j$(nproc)` should be quoted to avoid word splitting.  Hopefully no one will put spaces in `nproc`, but just in case `-j"$(nproc)"` would handle it better.  As noted in a comment above you may be able to drop this totally
2. Your `{.}.mp3` [bothers shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1083) which is also correctable with quoting like `'{.}.mp3'`.

## `if`s

I really like that you're using the direct `exit` value checking with your `if`s.  This is a great shell feature that is not terribly popular.

I wish you would indent them a bit better though:

```
if ! dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' ffmpeg | grep "ok installed"; then
    apt-get update  && apt-get install ffmpeg;
fi
```

Lining up the `if` and the `fi` makes me feel better.  Having the conditional things indented also helps following along much easier.

## shorter line length is good

You're already using `\` to split up the long `parallel` line, so why not split the `ffmpeg` part of it in two so it all fits in 80 columns?

## efficiency

Using `parallel` to manage the process seems like a good plan.  This operation should be CPU bound so it will do a good job for getting this done.  You might want to have some CPU and I/O monitoring going to make sure this is working as expected.

Your script does not seem to consider that some `mp3`s might already be there.  If your computer crashed in the middle of conversion you would be stuck redoing work already completed.

### `apt` minimization

While it is a tiny part of what you're doing the `apt` portion of things could be more efficient.  You could cache whether these commands are installed by touching a file like `~/.ready_to_convert` and hoping they don't get uninstalled by accident.  You could also choose to skip the `dpkg-query` and just see if `which ffmpeg` gives you any output.  This would let it work even if the commands are installed manually in `/usr/local/bin` without a package.

It would also be nice to only run `apt-get update` once.  You could set a flag like so:

```
if ! dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' ffmpeg | grep "ok installed"; then
    apt-get update  && apt-get install ffmpeg
    APT_UPDATED=1
fi

if ! dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' parallel | grep "ok installed"; then
    if [[ $APT_UPDATED < 1 ]]; then
        apt-get update
    fi
    apt-get install parallel
fi
```

But presumably the conversion is consuming most of the time so this will only let that get started a second or two quicker.

Comment: Given that we're on Ubuntu, why not simply `apt-get install shellcheck`, instead of depending on an online service?

Comment: `apt-get` usually goes out and downloads things so it does depend on online services.  So your question seems self-contradictory.

Comment: I don't recommend `apt-get` within the script - see my answer.  Fetching and installing packages is reasonably well secured using signatures, so it's pretty obvious if the repository gets compromised.  Another  difference is that shellcheck is an authoring activity (which you might want to automate, for example), and `apt-get` is a sysadmin activity.  Just an opinion; both options are available to those who want them!

Answer (score 5):

Please tell me you aren't running `ffmpeg` and other commands habitually as root!  As a regular user, you need `sudo` to install packages.

Test for the existence of the executables you actually need.  It's less work than querying the dpkg database.

You only need to run `apt-get update` once; all it does is obtain the latest list of packages from the APT repository.  Also, you only need to run `apt-get install` once; it will automatically disregard any package that is already installed.

```
if [ ! -x /usr/bin/ffmpeg -o ! -x /usr/bin/parallel ]; then
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ffmpeg parallel
fi
```

Note that you haven't tested for the [presence of the libmp3lame](https://askubuntu.com/q/13737/165556) encoder.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to hide the "ok installed" output when there is a match,
by passing the `-q` flag to `grep`.

The steps of installing `ffmpeg` and `parallel` are almost identical,
except for the command name.
It would better to extract such common logic into a function.

If both commands are missing, then the script will run `apt-get update` once for each,
which is a waste, as it would be enough to do once.

But the worst part of this script is that it requires root to run (to install stuff).
It's recommended to execute with root only the necessary minimum.
There's absolutely no need to be running as root when transcoding media files.

One solution would be to not require root to run the script,
but to use `sudo` for the steps that require it.
An even better solution would be to separate the installation of requirements and the main task of the script.
That is, use one script to install the requirements (only used once per machine),
and one script to perform the transcoding.

Answer (score 2):

Use a function to make lines shorter:

```
flac_to_mp3() {
    ffmpeg -n -i "$1" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k \
      -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "$2"
}
export -f flac_to_mp3

parallel flac_to_mp3 {} {.}.mp3 ::: */*/*/*.flac
```

Answer (score 1):

### Choice of shell

There seems to be nothing here that requires Bash rather than standard POSIX shell, so you could write `#!/bin/sh` instead.

### Handle command failures

The `apt-get install` lines will fail (unless you run the script as root - which you shouldn't; see below).  But the program will continue regardless.  The easiest way to fix this is to add `set -e` early in the script, to abort execution when commands fail in contexts where that's not already tested.

On a similar note, if any of the conversion commands fails, then it may leave an unfinished output file.  Re-running the script would fix this, but at the expense of repeating all the successful conversions.  We do have a tool that's well-suited to this job, and it's called Make:

```make
MP3_ARGS = -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3
MP3_FILES = $(patsubst %.flac,%.mp3,$(shell find . -name '%.flac'))

convert: $(MP3_FILES)
.PHONY: convert

%.mp3: %.flac
    ffmpeg -n -i $< $(MP3_ARGS) $@

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```

### Don't require unnecessary privilege

Normally, all the requirements are already fulfilled, and nothing will need to be installed.  If you really want to check dependencies, you could just print the list of packages to be installed, so that a root user can install them.  I think that's preferable to trying to do so within the script, when there's so much else that may fail (e.g. due to network connectivity).  It's also a bit rude to unexpectedly start downloading when it might be inconvenient (due to pricing, or due to competing traffic).

Here's the form of test I usually use:

```
die() { echo "$@" >&2; exit 1; }

# Check the preconditions
REQUIRED_TOOLS=(ffmpeg libmp3lame0 parallel)
MISSING_TOOLS=$(dpkg-query -Wf'${db:Status-Abbrev}${binary:Package}\n' "${REQUIRED_TOOLS[@]}" 2>&1 \
              | awk -e '/no packages/ { print $NF; }')
ERRORS="${MISSING_TOOLS:+Missing tools - please install: $MISSING_TOOLS}"

test -z "$ERRORS" || die "$ERRORS"
```

Comment: As others noted you can `sudo` to deal with `apt-get` within an unprivileged script.  Since this doesn't seem to be intended for others to use it probably won't cause any issue to be rude and aggressively install things.

Comment: Ah, but `sudo` uses PAM authentication, which might try to be interactive.  That really hampers running the script from `cron` or `at`.  And it still might be a surprise if you start pulling package files while others on your network are doing VoIP or streaming.

Comment: Some package installs are interactive too.  It is too bad that Debian has so much of that, but it can be worked around.  There's no indication from the OP that they intended this for unattended usage.  If you'd like to show how they would do that in your answer there might be somebody else that comes along that could benefit from this feature creep.

Comment: I think that's well enough addressed in [the answer by janos](/a/179378).